# excel activex command button

Tags: excel, activex

I have a spreadsheet model where I often need to sweep an input parameter.
I used to use Excel's built-in table function but that gave me problems, so now I just use some VBA code that manually does the sweeping.
The VBA code runs a loop where it changes the input parameter, calls Application.Calculate, stores the result and repeats.

I have found if I run this macro from a Forms control button it works fine.
But if I run the macro from an ActiveX Command Button it only works properly sometimes. Basically if I do not move the mouse at all after clicking the button the macro runs fine. But if I move the mouse before the loop is finished the results will be wrong from that point on.
I could use either version of the button on a sheet, but if I want to use a button on a userform I need to use the ActiveX variety. But then I can't move the mouse while the loop is running.

Has anyone else experienced this issue and found a fix?

Here is the macro I got from the web and modified slightly:

```
Sub IterateTables()
```

'Proof-of-Concept code for faster calculation of a 2-D What-If data table.  'Copyright Charles Williams, Decision Models 16-December-2015

```
Dim rngTable As Range
Dim rngRowCell As Range     'input variable cell location
Dim rngColCell As Range     'input variable cell location
Dim rngFormula As Range     'formula cell at top-left

Dim varRowSet As Variant    'set of input data on top row. 1D vector
Dim varColSet As Variant    'set of input data on left column. 1D vector
Dim varResults() As Variant 'Why parenthesis? Expect an 2D array? Why no parens for two above?

Dim nRows As Long
Dim nCols As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim k As Long

Dim varStartRowVal As Variant   'Initial value
Dim varStartColVal As Variant   'Iniitial value
Dim varFirstVal As Variant      'Initial value

Dim lCalcMode As Long
Dim blCalculated As Boolean
Dim dTime As Double
'
' get the location of what-if table and its formula cell
'Set rngTable = ActiveCell.CurrentRegion    ' expand active cell to the current region
Set rngTable = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E7:H12")
Set rngFormula = rngTable.Cells(1, 1)   ' Top-Left corner
nRows = rngTable.Rows.Count - 1         ' number of rows in the Column of what-if values
nCols = rngTable.Columns.Count - 1      ' number of columns in the row of what-if values
'
' get the row and column input cells using RefEdit on userform
'With ufIterTable
 '   .RefEditRow.Value = ""
  '  .RefEditCol.Value = ""
   ' .Show                   'Modal or non-modal userform?   ShowModal = True
    'If ufIterTable.RefEditRow.Value <> "" Then Set rngRowCell = Range(.RefEditRow.Value)
    'If ufIterTable.RefEditCol.Value <> "" Then Set rngColCell = Range(.RefEditCol.Value)
'End With

'HArd code insted of userform selection
Set rngRowCell = Range("F3")
Set rngColCell = Range("G3")

' if 2-D and we have got the row and column cells then proceed
If nRows > 0 And nCols > 0 And Not rngRowCell Is Nothing And Not rngColCell Is Nothing Then
    dTime = MicroTimer  'Start timer
    '
    ' create output results array
    ReDim varResults(1 To nRows, 1 To nCols)
    '
    ' get row and column arrays of what-if values
    varRowSet = rngFormula.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, nCols).Value2
    varColSet = rngFormula.Offset(1, 0).Resize(nRows, 1).Value2
    '
    ' set environment
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    lCalcMode = Application.Calculation
    If Application.Calculation <> xlCalculationManual Then Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    '
    ' can only skip initial values if workbook is calculated at start
    If Application.CalculationState = xlDone Then
        blCalculated = True
    Else
        blCalculated = False
    End If
    '
    ' Record initial start values for use at end
    varStartRowVal = rngRowCell.Value2
    varStartColVal = rngColCell.Value2
    varFirstVal = rngFormula.Value2
    '
    ' calculate result for each what-if values pair
    For j = 1 To nRows
        For k = 1 To nCols
            If blCalculated And varRowSet(1, k) = varStartRowVal And varColSet(j, 1) = varStartColVal Then
                '
                ' if what-if value pair is the same as the start values then skip recalc
                 varResults(j, k) = varFirstVal
            Else
                Application.StatusBar = "What-If Table Row " & j & " Column " & k       ' show calc status in the status bar
                '
                ' set values for this iteration, recalc, store result
                rngRowCell.Value2 = varRowSet(1, k)
                rngColCell.Value2 = varColSet(j, 1)
                Application.Calculate                   'Full calculate?
                varResults(j, k) = rngFormula.Value2
            End If
        Next k
    Next j
    '
    ' reset status bar
    Application.StatusBar = False
    '
    ' put results back to sheet
    rngFormula.Offset(1, 1).Resize(nRows, nCols) = varResults       'Write results array to sheet
    '
    ' reset both input cells back to initial values & recalc
    rngRowCell.Value2 = varStartRowVal
    rngColCell.Value2 = varStartColVal
    Application.Calculation = lCalcMode
    Application.Calculate
    '
    ' timer message
    dTime = Int((MicroTimer - dTime) * 1000) / 1000     'End timer
    MsgBox "Time for " & nRows * nCols & " Iterations: " & dTime & " Seconds"
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, John. In order for us to help you we need more information and (as a minimum) the VBA code which is potentially not working as intended. So, please [edit your post](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and include the VBA code you have written. To me, it sounds very much like there might be some `ActiveCell` (or similar) references in there which can easily mess-up things when you move the cursor or even dare to activate (click) on another sheet or file while the code is working.

Comment: Thanks for the code update. Just like I thought there are some unqualified references in this code which may very well cause the unwanted behavior. For example, there is a reference to `Range(.RefEditRow.Value)` in your code. Since no Excel file or sheet has been referenced this is automatically translated to `ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range(.RefEditRow.Value)`. So, if you activate another Excel file or another sheet then your code is very likely to "misbehave": http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1576/common-mistakes/5110/qualifying-references#t=20170420133714205886

Comment: That was in the original code I downloaded. I simplified things and edited that out. There is only one workbook open and it has only one sheet in it.